# write a row to csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to write days to csv file using pandas. I used below method

```
#create new df
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':day})
df.to_csv('test.csv', mode='a', index = False, header=False)
```

This writes to the csv with dates in new rows.
Something like below...

```
01-08-2018
02-08-2018
03-08-2018
04-08-2018
```

I want all the dates to be in one row and it should start by leaving the first column because I want my csv to look something like below...

```
       01/08/18  02/08/18  03/08/18 ...
Heena
Megha
Mark
```

I am new to pandas so I am not getting the idea to deal with it.

Comment: You want to transpose the dataframe? There isn't much for us to go on here, where has `Heena`, `megha` etc. appeared from?

Comment: In any file system, you cannot directly "prepend" to a file. If you one to add line to the beginning of the file, by Pandas or not, you need to read in the whole file, write the first line, then write the whole file back down.

Comment: @raganjosh, I was not aware of transpose. Just looked into it and I guess I can try transpose.

Comment: @THN, I admit. I have to write back to the file after reading it.

Comment: Yes, that and transpose will solve it for you. If the processing is complicated, you may want to do all in pandas, then write the final df down.

Answer (score 3):

Try to transpose the dataframe before writing.

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame()
>>> df['co1']=pd.date_range(start='08/01/18',periods=4)
>>> df.T
         0          1          2          3
co1 2018-08-01 2018-08-02 2018-08-03 2018-08-04

>>> df.T.to_csv('test.csv',mode='a',index=False,header=False)
```